# I'm trying to animate a text view's position and height but the height just gets set and the position animates

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation, ios-animations

I'm trying to animate an instance of `UITextView` to expand and collapse some text but what happens is that the text view gets resized with a new height right away and its position animates. Ideally I'd want both properties to animate for smoother animation.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:kCaptionAnimationDuration * 10
                 animations:^{
                     [self->_caption setFrame:self->_truncatedCaptionFrame];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     self->_displayingFullCaption = NO;
                 }];
```

How can I get the height to slowly animate instead?

Comment: It works correctly in my project, both position and size animated as expected. can you provide more info? iOS version, device model. check thread, it must be in main thread.

Comment: Hmm yeah I've tested on my own UIView object and it seems to work fine but not for this specific view.

Comment: what kind of the view is?

Comment: It's a UITextView for both views

Comment: Are there embedded some constraints to the view?

Comment: There are no constraints embedded. THe view is laid out programmatically